# How to install mysql in my Django project using pip or any other tool in python 3.7

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I've build a django project using python 3.7, Now I'm trying to deploy my project on Google App engine, and trying to use mysql locally for testing. After going through multiple question/answers/documentation still I'm unable to install mysql correctly.

I tried following options:

1. `pip install mysqlclient`
2. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
3. `pip3 install http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip`
4. `pip install mysql-connect-python`
5. `pip install pymysql`

But none of the above is working for me.

Comment: Try `pip install django mysqlclient`

Comment: "But none of the above is working for me." We need more info about what specifically is not working.

Comment: You can try to install it manually by downloading the wheel and running setup.py